# Frequency is ignored for auto renewable memberships

Tags: civimember, issues

If I setup a membership that has a duration in months (e.g. 12 months) the duration is ignored.

I'm able to repeat this on the [demo site](https://cividemo.com). It is somewhat described already in the open [issue 3344](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3344) so I updated that with how I got it to happen. (perhaps instead I should open a new issue?)

- created a new membership type with a duration of 12 months, fixed, starting on the 1st (our memberships last one year and always end at the end of the month). Set the auto renew option to be "Give option but not required". Its named "test Membership".
- edited the existing contribution page "Company Membership Page" to have this membership as an option with auto renew set as "Give Option".

I then went [to that page](https://cividemo.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2), selected this membership, and checked "Renew automatically", filled in required info and pressed "Review Contribution". The page shown states:

```
Total Amount: $1.00
I want this membership to be renewed automatically every 1 month(s).
```

It is ignoring the duration of 12 months.

It is also submitting to our payment processor (paypal) incorrectly. We had to process refunds due to this issue.

Comment: I should add that this started sometime around version 5.49 or 5.50. Prior to upgrading this was working fine.

Comment: concur i can see this behaviour. silly question, but why not choose '1 year' instead of '12 months'?

Comment: We used to have one year, but I don't recall why it was a problem. Maybe I will try that again.

Comment: Just tried it. We have memberships that end on the last day of the month and start on the first. If you choose 12 months and fixed, it then lets you pick 1 to 31 for the start date. If you choose 1 year and fixed then you can only pick a month and day (e.g. Jan 01). So for a fixed membership start date by month that is the only option that works.

Comment: This seems to be a rather major bug. Even if the work around would be to use a rolling year membership it would not allow for something like a 6 month membership. I'm going to open a new issue because although 3344 is similar it is (perhaps) not the same issue.

Comment: Created https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3810