# CiviCRM 3 Month subscription being charged every month,

Tags: recurring-contributions, stripe

We have a quarterly subscription

[image]

Image shows how membership is set up.

We have this in a price set and on a contribution page.

We are using stripe for the payment processor.

Core and stripe plugins are up to date.

(everything is in test mode).

When we test the membership everything goes through BUT we can see that the recurring contribution shows every 1 month - not every 3 as expected.
[image]

What am I missing?

Any ideas?

Comment: seems similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42486/frequency-is-ignored-for-auto-renewable-memberships which resulted in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3810

Comment: sounds like there is a fix waiting for a PR at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3344

Comment: if you are up for trying Tom's suggested fix and report back then it could help get this fix committed